# Fetch rows ordered in maximum matching conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Table1:

```
Field    Type    KEY
ID       int     PRI
Name     varchar 
SubID    varchar PRI
```

Table2:

```
Field    Type    KEY
ID       int     PRI/ForignKey
SubName  varchar
```

So i want to fetch on the basis of subName ordered by maximum number of matching subname Table1.

e.g.

```
ID    Name   SubID 
1     Shan   1
1     Shan   2
2     ABC    1

ID    subName
1     SST
2     Chemistry
3     Physics
```

So i want to fetch records with condition like having subName SST or Chemistry ordered by the maximum matching records.
In our case, it should return:

```
Shan
Abc
```

As shan is matching both the conditions, so it is on top.
Please provide the mysql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Name
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.SubID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.Name 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN subName IN ('SST', 'Chemistry') THEN 1 END) > 0
ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN subName IN ('SST', 'Chemistry') THEN 1 END) DESC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08219/1)